# how to let threads work indepdently in TCP server

Tags: c++, multithreading, tcp, server

I am working on a multithreading TCP server, but I have problem with how to make threads work independently after creating them. My code is as follows:

```
int handler( int *client_fd, int i )
{
     // receive TCP message and parse it here 
     recv(....);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
     // set up network connection

     while( true )
     {
          if ( ( client_fd = accept( ... ) ) > 0 )
          {
                std::thread th ( handler, &client_fd, i );
                th.join();
          }
     }
}
```

This approach does not work because the server serves threads in sequence: start the operations for the second thread only after finishing the first thread. I think this is because th.join() function makes the main function wait to proceed to second accept operation until the first thread finishes.

But what I want is to parallel process multiple tasks from multiple client connections. What should I do?

Comment: Get rid of the join?

Comment: That will trade off sequential thread execution for an abort. Merely getting rid of the join results in the newly-constructed thread object going out of scope and getting destroyed, and since there's a running thread there, you'll end up with an immediate abort. Try again.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks.  My point to the OP was if you want concurrency why are you joining at all? I assumed there was more to it, hence it was a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining, use `detach`() to detach the thread. The thread will continue running, the `std::thread` object's constructor will clean itself up, and your main execution thread resumes waiting for the next accepted socket.

That answers the first part of your question, the "parallel process" part of it. The answer second part, "what should I do", is something that you'll need to answer for yourself. Only you know the complete requirements of your larger application.

If your application does have a need to join execution threads, for some particular reasons, obviously you will need to find an alternative to your requirement. There are various, different approaches one can take, in order to implement robust, effective thread management. The best approach really depends on your exact requirements, which you will need to analyze for yourself.